# 1996 Nissan Sentra won’t start after refueling

Tags: nissan, ignition, fuel-pump

I’ve had this car for about a month, and never had a single problem starting up. This morning, after filling the gas tank, I turn the key and absolutely nothing. No electronics or anything. I tried to push start it among a few other checks, and after sitting for about 20 min, the electronics came back on. So, I tried to start it, and sure enough, it started right up.

I pulled it into a parking spot and shut it off, and turn it back on, without issue 3 more times. I thought maybe I had cleared some air from the fuel lines or something (I don’t know), but after parking it to grab some food, same thing. It doesn’t crank, no electronics. After some searching, it seems like fuel pumps sometimes fail after refueling from low amounts of gas. I had about a quarter tank before, so it’s not out of the question, but does seem odd.

I can’t really get passed the fact that it must have something to do with refueling. Code scanner does not connect because the electronics never turn on.

What else could be the issue?

Comment: Check the battery cable connections at the battery, remove and clean if needed.

Comment: Were you sat for 20 minutes with the ignition turned on, then the dash lit up without touching the ignition key switch at all?

Comment: @handyhowie, no I would turn the ignition on periodically after checking various things, like oil and fuses, to see it came back on...and one time, it did! Though, I doubt anything I checked had anything to do with the dash lights coming back.

Comment: Did you found the problem? What was it? Please let us know

Comment: @PeterM.-standsforMonica I don't know for sure because I moved away and sold the car, but I think Paulster2's answer is likely correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking at the wrong area of the car. If the electronics didn't come on, this is an electrical power issue, not a fueling issue. I'd check to ensure all connections are good from the battery, to wires, etc. Make sure your ground connection is clean. Make sure the battery is up to snuff (you may need to take it to an auto parts store and have it load tested). I've had the same issue you're talking about before, and it is always a bad connection some place.

Comment: I never found out if this was definitely the right answer, because moved out of the country and sold the car, but I think it's more than likely correct.

After inspecting, it seemed there was a bolt missing from the positive battery connector as well as some corrosion that may have been interfering with the connection. I would get mixed results from fiddling with the connector–perhaps a new bolt and battery without corrosion would have fixed the problem permanently.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @paulster2 suggests, following on from your comment -

> "I would turn the ignition on periodically after checking various
>   things, like oil and fuses, to see it came back on...and one time, it
>   did!"

I would also be checking for a faulty ignition switch.